# WAR packaging error: TypeError: cannot find function bind in object

Tags: grails, war

I'm with this error for days and I really need some help.
WAR packaging error: typeerror: cannot find function bind in object
I have this error when I building war file from a Grails Application using Netbeans IDE.

```
WAR packaging error: TypeError: Cannot find function bind in object 
    function (deps, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(deps)) {
        var params = deps.map(function (dep) {
            return this.lookup(dep);
        }, this);
        if (callback) {
            callback.apply(null, params);
        }
        return undefined;
    } else {
        return this.lookup(deps);
    }
}  (/GrailsProject/target/work/resources/uglifyjs/source-map.js#153)
```

And I don't know how to fix that. I tried clean it, deleting target folder, even I put all files from proyect to another and same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a couple of odd Grails errors over the years that have been solved by deleting the Grails cache. On a windows machine it's stored under the "./grails/" directory in your user's home. I don't use NetBeans, but I believe they also have a cached folder there too.